# Write and Read Cookies in different Applications

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have two applications running in Jboss, can I write a cookie in a application and read in another?

For example, if I have two Servlets:
 - WriterCookieServlet on localhost:8080/Application1
 - ReaderCookieServlet on localhost:8080/Application2

WriterCookieServlet:

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", "cookieValue");
 response.addCookie(cookie);
 response.sendRedirect("localhost:8080/Application2");
```

Then on ReaderCookieServlet I want read this cookie.

Comment: AFAIK, this should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @galuano1 is right: this should indeed be possible. Make sure the *path* is correct, though. It is used to determine whether a certain cookie is visible to a web-application.

From the [Cookie Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html):

> The cookie is visible to all the pages in the directory you specify, and all the pages in that directory's subdirectories. A cookie's path must include the servlet that set the cookie, for example, */catalog*, which makes the cookie visible to all directories on the server under */catalog*.
>
> Consult RFC 2109 (available on the Internet) for more information on setting path names for cookies.

I'd say you should use `/` for directory, since both applications will have a different context root.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the domain specified in the cookie is same ( here localhost ) , cookie can be read by the two different applications

Answer (score 0):

It is true: cookie can thoerically be read by the application if it comes from the same domain. This mean that the application has it available, it doesn't imply the application has available the secrets needed to interpret it
The problem here may not be related to the theorical part but on the technology part: if the cookie is not in clear text (as it should be) it requires to be opened by the target application who needs to read the content
This usually comes out of the box if the application which forge the cookie is the same application that needs to read it. 
But if it is forged by an application 1 and needs to be decrypted by an application 2, you need to ensure this command you used:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", "cookieValue");
```

doesn't use any application specific secret to encrypt the cookie, otherwise it can never be opened by a different application. 
Of course the answer may change according the technology you are using, don't know the behaviour in Java, I am aware many technologies to use machine based secrets to encrpyt and sign the cookie.